# prove $\left|\frac{az+b}{\overline{b}z+\overline{a}}\right|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $|z|=1$
Show that
$$\left|\frac{az+b}{\overline{b}z+\overline{a}}\right|=1$$

I'm thinking of conjugating that bottom, but i'm curious as to how the modulus around the expression would affect arithmetic operations. I'm just getting into complex analysis so i'm having a little of trouble with the formulas.

the formula that i am aware of with modulus is $|z|^2=z*\overline{z}$ but since there isn't a square here, i don't think i can use it. Unless i turn it into a square which is also a possibility.
$$\left|\frac{az+b}{\overline{b}z+\overline{a}}\right|^2=1$$

Having $a$ and $b$ as complex numbers themselves is making this confusing for me. would appreciate any help

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then $\bar{z} = \frac{1}{z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|az + b| = |\bar{a}\bar{z}+\bar{b}| = \left|\bar{a}\frac{1}{z}+\bar{b}\right| = \left|\frac{\bar{a} +\bar{b}z}{z}\right| = |\bar{a} + z\bar{b}|$$

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think of it that way. Just one question thought, how does the last equality hold?

Comment: $$\left|\bar{a}\frac{1}{z}+\bar{b}\right| = \left|\frac{\bar{a} +\bar{b}z}{z}\right|  =\frac{|\bar{a} +\bar{b}z|}{|z|} =  |\bar{a} + z\bar{b}|$$ since $|z| = 1$